# Bizarre readfile() issue

Tags: php

My script is the following:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='test.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("www.example.com/test.pdf");
?>
```

Now if I change readfile to say:

```
// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("test.pdf");
```

It works fine, if however I specify and absolute URL,     `readfile("www.example.com/test.pdf");`

the PDF does not open up. The above only seems to work locally.

Does anybody know why absolute url's are not working? Cheers

Solution:

```
// The PDF source is in original.pdf 

readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test.pdf");
```

This function only works with absolute paths, not urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are missing the protocol: `http://`
- And check your `allow_url_fopen` settings!
- Turn on error reporting

.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

A smarter approach would be to store/cache the remote file localy, so you don't have to download it every time. And it would take the load off the target site.

Comment: And it still doesn't work? Did you turn on the error reporting?

Comment: try saving a local copy (using `file_get_contents` perhaps) and then pass it to the `readfile()` And don't forget to check your error logs!

Comment: Ok, I have tried this on my local machine, it seems to work fine. On my web server. PHP settings within php.ini file is the same. Could it be because I am using the https: protocol on the web server instead of http?

Comment: Ok tried file_get contents, get the following errors Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/test.pdf) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream

Comment: Are you sure the path is corrent and you have the permissions?

Comment: Solved the problem: // The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test.pdf"); - this function only works with absolute paths, not urls.

Answer (score 0):

A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) wrappers have been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..,

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='test.pdf'");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile("http://www.example.com/test.pdf");
?>
```

without "http://" you cannot download.

Comment: Tried that, am I better off using cURL to call the file?

Comment: To elaborate on this: If you leave out `http://`, your (thejoker's) PHP script will attempt to find the file in a directory named `www.example.com` on the local machine. It doesn't know that it's a URL unless you tell it. Like mishu says in another answer, this will only work if the setting `allow_url_fopen` is on.

Comment: check the file permissions, no need for cURL at all

Comment: I have read that it is a bad idea to enable allow_url_fopen - will there be a security flaw if I enabled it?